# Raspberry Pi camera and OpenCv: 10bit?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

The Raspberry Pi Camera v1 contains a [OmniVision OV5647](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/) sensors which offers up to [10bit raw RGB data](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/RaspberryPi/ov5647_full.pdf). Using opencv's `cvQueryFrame` I get only 8bit data. I am only interested in grayscale imagery - how do I get 10bit data?

Comment: The property doesn't seem to be there... http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set

Comment: Do you want to do high speed video processing, or fairly slow single frames?

Comment: @MarkSetchell For my application I only need single frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be simpler options available, but here are a couple of possible ideas. I have not coded or tested either, like I normally would - sorry.

#### Option 1.

Use *"Video for Linux"* (v4l2) and open the camera, do the `ioctl()s` and manage the buffers yourself - great link [here](https://jwhsmith.net/2014/12/capturing-a-webcam-stream-using-v4l2/).

#### Option 2.

Use `popen()` to start `raspivid` and tell it you want the raw option (`--raw`) and grab the raw data off the end of the JPEG with information on Bayer decoding from - [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=357138). Other, somewhat simpler to follow information available at section 5.11 [here](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html).

Comment: Well, it seem that this is what I have to do. I was kinda hoping there would be some trick I could use so that I wouldn't have to rewrite the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to capture RAW data from **still** images and not necessarily video, you have 2 options I know of:

## Option 1: picamera

[picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io) is a Python library that will let you capture data to a stream. Be sure to read the docs as it's pretty tricky to work with.

## Option 2: raspistill

You can also shell out to `raspistill` to capture your image file, and the process that however you want - if you want to process the raw data (captured `raspistill --raw`), you can use [picamraw](https://github.com/OsmoSystems/picamraw/pull/4) on- or offboard the Pi.

Even though we're a heavily Python shop, my team went with option 2 (in combination with picamraw, which we released ourselves) because picamera was not stable enough.